# i am trying to send from one controller to other contoller in angularjs but is not working

Tags: angularjs

```
/*service */
 app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var property = 'First';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };
    });


/*first contoller */
app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$location,$http,$window,sharedProperties){
    $scope.submit =function(){
        var username=$scope.username;
        var pass=$scope.password;
      sharedProperties.setProperty(username);          


 $location.path('/userdashboard');
 $window.location.reload();
            });
        }  
    });

/*second controller*/
app.controller('empController', function($route,$scope,$http,$routeParams,sharedProperties){

    $scope.getEmployees = function(){

        alert( sharedProperties.getProperty());

     };    
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Service does not need to return anything. You have to assign everything in this variable. Because service will create instance by default and use that as a base object.

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
     this.property = 'First';
});
```

Then in controller

```
sharedProperties.property = $scope.username;
```

Had you been looking to use `factory`

```
app.factory('sharedProperties', function () {
       var factory = {};
       factory.property = 'Hello';  

       factory.setProperty = function (value) {
            factory.property = value;
       };    
       return factory;
});
```

Then in controller you would use it

```
sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.username);    // Setter
$scope.var = sharedProperties.property;  //getter
```

EDIT

[**Working Plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CUy9t85ru6iMZhkf9y7P?p=preview)

Comment: Neel i have set the sharedProperties.setProperty($scope.username); in one contoller and while geeting it from  other controller it displays property as first it was not modified to given username...

Comment: I SET THE VALUE IN ONE CONTROLLER AND GETTING IN SAME CONTROLLER IT DISPLAY CORRECT ONE BUT WHEN I AM GETTING THE VALUE AND DISPLAY IN SECOND CONTROLLER IT SHOWS "UNDEFINED" PLEASE HELP TO SOLVE IT....

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work for you. :

```
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

            <button ng-click="sendData();"></button>

        </div>


        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                function sendData($scope) {
                    var arrayData = [1,2,3];
                    $scope.$emit('someEvent', arrayData);
                }

            });
            app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, data) {
                    console.log(data); 
                }); 
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign members to $rootScope, which will store data globally for your app.  Just inject $rootScope to each controller.

For instance...

```
 /*first controller */        
app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,$location,$http,$window,sharedProperties){
            $scope.submit =function(){
                var username=$scope.username;
                var pass=$scope.password;
                $rootScope.username = username;          


                $location.path('/userdashboard');
                $window.location.reload();
            });
        }  
    });
```

This will make 'username' available to any controller that injects and consumes $rootScope.

```
/*second controller*/
app.controller('empController', function($route,$scope,$rootScope,$http,$routeParams,sharedProperties){

    $scope.getEmployees = function(){
        alert($rootScope.username);
     };    
   };
```